# jQuery scrolling buttons stop working if clicked too rapidly

Tags: jquery

http://vc4hp.net/temp/4/test.htm

If you click "Scroll Left" rapidly you should be able to click it at least a few times in a row.

Then you need to click "Scroll Right" lots of times but it eventually works.

Then the next time "Scroll Left" never seems to work again...

(BTW I can't seem to get it to work at all in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dmya/ )

Comment: You hadn't defined `scrolltime` in your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dmya/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution prevents a double trigger on the animation, it only binds to the button that should be able to trigger, and unbinds as soon as it is clicked:

```
var scrolltime = 1000;

var scroll_left = function(e) {
  $('#scroll_left').unbind('click');
  $('#scroll_right').click(scroll_right);
  $('#left_content').animate({
    left: '-50%'
  }, scrolltime, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  $('#right_content').animate({
    left: '50%'
  }, scrolltime, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}

var scroll_right = function(e) { 
  $('#scroll_right').unbind('click');
  $('#scroll_left').click(scroll_left);
  $('#left_content').animate({
    left: '50%'
  }, scrolltime, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  $('#right_content').animate({
    left: '150%'
  }, scrolltime, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#scroll_left').click(scroll_left);
    //$('#scroll_right').click(scroll_right);
});
​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dmya/3/

Comment: It's a nice way of reusing functions to do exactly things like that :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/3Dmya/4/

Calling `$.stop()` seems to work for me, but I was having difficulty reliably reproducing the bug.

`stop` with the first parameter set to true clears the current animation queue, so when the button is clicked repeatedly, only one of the bound animation events will execute.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
var scrolltime = 3000;

$('#scroll_left').click(function(e) {
    $('#left_content').stop(true).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, scrolltime, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $('#right_content').stop(true).animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, scrolltime, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});

$('#scroll_right').click(function(e) {
    $('#left_content').stop(true).animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, scrolltime, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $('#right_content').stop(true).animate({
        left: '150%'
    }, scrolltime, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I thought of that just then though if you click it multiple times it slows down - unless you also change the animation to "linear".

Comment: I get color lines during the animation of scroll left. Is anyone else seeing these?

Comment: I get a kind of yellow trail in Google Chrome 21: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dmya/2/ The trail disappears if you resize the window...